# How to override generic method java

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface which just contains one generic method:

```
public interface Presenter {
    <T> void query(T queryParameter);
}
```

Now, I want to define a subclass of `Presenter` and I want the type to be `String`, just like this:

```
public class IpQueryPresenter implements Presenter {
    void query(String queryParameter) {
         //do something here...
    }
}
```

How to define it ?

I saw all your answers define the type on the interface name, but is it a must ? Is it possible if I just want to define a generic method and override it ?

Comment: Btw, "I have a class ..." is not correct, `Presenter` is an interface :)

Comment: In your example `IpQueryPresenter` is not a subclass of `Presenter` (or of anything else); also `Presenter` is an interface, not a class.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `T` on the interface, i.e. like this:

```
public interface Presenter<T> {
 void query(T queryParameter);
}
```

Then set the type in the implementation:

```
public class IpQueryPresenter implements Presenter<String> {
  //note that you need to make the method public
  public void query(String queryParameter) {
     //do something here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and answer, but I still wonder that is it possible to do this without defining `T` on the interface ?

Comment: @L.Swifter that wouldn't really make sense since defining `T` on the method would mean you want to infer the type from the assignment or the parameters. Additionally think of operating on a variable like `Presenter p`. How should the compiler know that a certain implementation of that interface only allows strings (and why should it bother in your opinion)?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, from your code I'm assuming you are implementing an interface, not extending a class (though your `IpQueryPresenter` class has neither `extends` or `implements` clause).

You can move the generic type parameter to the interface level :

```
public interface Presenter<T> {
    void query(T queryParameter);
}
```

And then :

```
public class IpQueryPresenter implements Presenter<String> {
    void query(String queryParameter) {
         //do something here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the interface itself generic and define your type in your sub class

```
public interface Presenter<T> {
    void query(T queryParameter);
}

public class IpQueryPresenter implements Presenter<String>  {
    void query(String queryParameter) {
         //do something here...
    }
}
```